# Standard Salesforce convert into custom object

Tags: leads

Im using standard salesforce lead and I want to create the opportunity in the custom object once the lead has been converted with checked create opportunity.

How can I achieve this? How could I detect when the checkbox to create opportunity in the lead conversion is checked?
I checked the workbench on Lead object but I did not find the field.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The field was not visible in Lead Object, but you do the below steps : -

1. do the following query :

   SELECT ConvertedOpportunityId FROM Lead WHERE Id = '00Q90000001LVVh'//Lead Id

If your checkbox **"Do not create a new opportunity upon conversion"** is check while converting the lead, the **ConvertedOpportunityId**  field will remain blank, if you uncheck the checkbox the field will be populated with the created opportunity Id.

2. based on the field **ConvertedOpportunityId**  field you can create opportunity records in your specified custom object based on your logic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but that means that a record has already been created in the standard object. Is there any way that I dont need to create opportunity records?

Comment: see if you check the checkbox, salesforce will definitely create opportunity record and it is OOTB functionality. what you can do you can delete the opportunity created by standard process after your custom opportunity creation.